# WebSocket interface cannot be used in place of WebSocket?

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket

I'm following a guide to try and set up a `WebSocket.Server` using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and Express 4 with NodeJS and TypeScript. Problem is that the guide I'm following (found here: https://morioh.com/p/3b302785a62f) seems like it's out of date or something because the code provided doesn't work.

I'm trying to use an extended websocket object to keep track of an alive connection. It looks like this:

```js
interface ExtWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    isAlive: boolean;
}
```

Now doing this, as the code in the tutorial shows, I get an error:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((ws: ExtWebSocket) => {
        if (!ws.isAlive) return ws.terminate();
        ws.isAlive = false;
        ws.ping(null, false, true);
    });
}, 10000);
```

The error states that I cannot use the ExtWebSocket in the `forEach` loop but I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Probably because according to the type definitions `wss.clients` contains `WebSocket` objects, not `ExtWebSocket` objects so TypeScript won't let you try to use `ExtWebSocket` properties/methods on something that is declared as a `WebSocket` object.

Comment: I just don't understand how the post I linked then seemingly managed to do it (it's at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you can't 'de-narrow' a WebSocket to an ExtWebSocket since it extends WebSocket. If you had an ExtWebSocket, then you could narrow it down to a WebSocket but not vice-versa.

Here is a link to the typescript handbook on this topic: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: I'm new to typescript so I might need to have that explained a bit more. ExtWebSocket extends the WebSocket, so an ExtWebSocket *is* a WebSocket right? Or does TS use this concept differently?

Comment: @OmniOwl https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html